# Editing layout of a seekbar with custom image doesn't work

Tags: android, seekbar

I need to edit the layout of a seekbar. The seekbar layout file I have:

```
<SeekBar
           android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:progress="0"
           android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek"
           android:thumb="@drawable/thumb" />
```

And the drawable/seek is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/time_passivo"/>
  <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/time_attivo" />

  </layer-list>
```

I want something like this image:

[image: wrong seek]

But instead I get this:

[image: correct seek]

Simply I use 2 images for the seek... (on png)
 [image: time_attivo]

 [image: time_passivo]

and thumb is another png

**Edit**

I tried to do it with a 9path, but it didn't solve my problem.

the 9path is:
[image: time_attivo_9patch]

[image: time_passivo_9patch]

but the seek didn't work [image: seek]

Comment: post `@drawable/time_passivo` and `@drawable/time_attivo` looks to me like you tried to make 9patch images and don't have them set up exactly correct. But we can't tell without being able to see your drawables.

Comment: You're talking about the size of the seekbar? To give you some help about that we will need to know the wrapping layout view. So please add the complete (or at least more) of the layout xml.

Comment: i've insert the 2 image time_attivo and time_passivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the question.
I didn't use the static picture, but drew it all with code

the bar:

`<SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            style="@style/PowerSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TextViewStop"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewStart"
            android:minHeight="6dp"
            android:maxHeight="6dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingRight="5dip"
            android:progress="2"

            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb" />`

and the style:

`<!--  Seekbar player -->
     <style name="PowerSeekBar" parent="android:Widget.SeekBar">
      <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/seek</item>
      <item name="android:thumbOffset">0dip</item>
   </style>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
     android:id="@android:id/background">
      <shape>
         <corners
           android:radius="3dip" />
         <gradient
           android:startColor="#ffcccccc"
           android:endColor="#9d9d9d"
           android:centerY="0.50"
           android:angle="270" />
      </shape>
   </item>

   <item
     android:id="@android:id/progress">
      <clip>
         <shape>
            <corners
              android:radius="3dip" />
            <gradient
              android:startColor="#ffd92034"
              android:endColor="#ffad192a"
              android:angle="270" />
         </shape>
      </clip>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

thanks to all.